MCAT resistor question
Example: Consider two resistors wired in parallel with R1 = 5Ω and R2 = 10Ω. If the voltage across them is 10 V, what is the current through each of the two resistors?
Solution: First, the current flowing through the whole circuit must be found. To do this, the equivalent resistance must be calculated:
  1/Rp = 1/R1 + 1/R2 = 1/5Ω + 1/10Ω = 3/10Ω  Rp = 10/3 Ω  
Why does this not equal 2/15Ω?

Why would it equal 2/15 Ω?

Because you multiply 1/5 by 2/2 to make it a common denominator with 1/10 instead of adding denominators together.

Reopening !!!! .................

This is an algebra question, not an electronics question.
In general if you want to add \$\frac{a}{b}\text{ to }\frac{c}{d} \$ you must find a common denominator, then you can add the numerators (and retain the common denominator).
The mindless way is to take \$\frac{a}{b}\text{ + }\frac{c}{d} \text{ = } \frac{a\cdot d}{b \cdot d}\text{ + }\frac{c\cdot b }{d\cdot b} \text { = }
  \frac{a \cdot d +c \cdot b}{b \cdot d} \$
In this case we have 1/5 and 1/10 so we have (10+5)/50 = 15/50 = 3/10
In this case there is a common factor so we can multiply the numerator and denominator of 1/5 by 2 to get 2/10 and then we can add it to 1/10 to get 3/10.

Thank you! I didn't comprehend it from the wording. It must be sleep deprivation! I appreciate how you put that out. Something about the example beforehand tricked my mind without thinking it through. I understand now.
LCD :)

I don't see why it would be what you suggest.
However, the task is to solve how much current is through each of the resistors.
So the way the solution approaches the problem is not even needed. There is no need to calculate the total resistance of the two parallel resistors as it is not needed anywhere.
You have two resistors in parallel, 5 and 10 ohms, and 10 volts over both of them. You can just calculate directly how much current goes through each of the resistors and stop calculating right there because you have the answers needed.
Then, you will also see that you have total of 3A flowing with 10V which must also mean the equivalent resistance is 10/3 ohms, which you know was already expected from the example solution.
